# Getting 502 Bad Gateway and then redirected to another website. Scrapy

Tags: shell, redirect, scrapy

scrapy mega noob here.

When I try to scrapy shell a website like for example:

```
scrapy shell https://shop.coles.com.au/a/a-vic-metro-oakleigh/product/gasmate-cartridge-butane
```

I get the following messages:

```
...
[scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
[scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://shop.coles.com.au/a/a-vic-metro-oakleigh/product/gasmate-cartridge-butane> (failed 1 times): 502 Bad Gateway
[scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://shop.coles.com.au/a/a-vic-metro-oakleigh/product/gasmate-cartridge-butane> (failed 2 times): 502 Bad Gateway
[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://shop.coles.com.au/a/a-vic-metro-oakleigh/product/gasmate-cartridge-butane> (referer: None)
...
```

Then when I try to see what the response.body has:

```
In [1]: print(response.body)
b'<html><body><script>var $j=\'c\';$3=\'c\';$q=\'c\';$G=\'f\';$s=\'c\';$F=\'c\';$X=\'c\';$t=\'c\';$H=\'c\';$e=\'=\';$D=\'c\';$g=\'c\';$8=\'c\';$A=\'c\';$6=\'c\';$O=\'=\';$P=\'c\';$U=\'5\';$4=\'6\';$y=\'c\';$v=\'c\';$u=\'c\';$b=\'c\';$V=\'b\';$r=\'5\';$2=\'6\';$Q=\'f\';$R=\'c\';$5=\'c\';$9=\'c\';$c=\'c\';$S=\'c\';$l=\'c\';$k=\'c\';$m=\'_\';$M=\'5\';$N=\'c\';$C=\'c\';$d=\'c\';$J=\'b\';$E=\'5\';$1=\'6\';$i=\'f\';document.cookie=(!4?$j:"")+(!""?$3:"")+(!4?$q:"")+(!4?$G:"")+(!({})?$s:"")+(!NaN?$F:"")+(!NaN?$X:"")+(![]?$t:"")+(!0?$H:"")+(![]?$e:"")+(!4?$D:"")+(!""?$g:"")+(!""?$8:"")+(![]?$A:"")+(!NaN?$6:"")+(!NaN?$O:"")+(![]?$P:"")+(!0?$U:"")+(!({})?$4:"")+(!4?$y:"")+(!""?$v:"")+(!0?$u:"")+(!0?$b:"")+(!""?$V:"")+(!0?$r:"")+(!0?$2:"")+(!""?$Q:"")+(!0?$R:"")+(!NaN?$5:"")+(!""?$9:"")+(!NaN?$c:"")+(!""?$S:"")+(!""?$l:"")+(!NaN?$k:"")+(!0?$m:"")+(!0?$M:"")+(!""?$N:"")+(!NaN?$C:"")+(!NaN?$d:"")+(!NaN?$J:"")+(!""?$E:"")+(!""?$1:"")+(!0?$i:"")+\'; path=/\';window.location.href=window.location.href;</script></body></html'
```

Which is not the website HTML, I can check in a Browser that the HTML of `https://shop.coles.com.au/a/a-vic-metro-oakleigh/product/gasmate-cartridge-butane` is totally different, therefore I know I'm being redirected to somewhere.

***Question is*** how and why this is happening? and most importantly how to avoid it?

*Additional info:* I'm using a proxy service that will use random proxies each time I use Scrapy shell from a pool of over 20.000. 
It's also worth noting that I've been scraping this webpage for quite a long time before this issue started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the Javascript code, it sets a cookie and redirects on itself.

It seems that the website expects you to have a specific cookie to access the "normal" pages, but since scrapy can't execute javascript, it stops there.

You may want to parse the Javascript code somehow, and set your cookie manually and re-query the same URL.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you